# Git command line equivalent of Sourcetree's reverse hunk between two arbitrary commits

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-revert

Suppose two branches, B and D, share a common ancestor commit A:

```
A -- B
  \_ C -- D
```

In Sourcetree, in addition to seeing the changes between B and D (`git diff B..D`), there's also an option to reverse the hunks and lines in the diff i.e. apply the diffed changes between B and D onto commit B or vice versa.

Using Sourcetree to reverse the hunks in the diff didn't cause any conflicts but my attempt to use `git revert B..D` from the command line resulted in a conflict. Is there a way to do accomplish this via the command line without causing conflict?

Comment: I'm not sure I am getting it. If you diff `B..D` and then try to _revert_ that on top of B (which does not have C or D in its history), it's very likely that it will fail (hence, conflicts).... unless B somehow duplicates stuff from C and D without pointing to it in history.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the reason it fails. Perhaps I should have clarified that it managed to work in Sourcetree without conflicts but not in the command line. Sourcetree has options to reverse commits and also reverse hunks. It's able to diff two commits and reverse hunks in said diff. Although it can fail if the working directory isn't clean or if you try to reverse the same hunk more than once, I didn't have any conflicts using Sourcetree for the example above.

Comment: `git diff` has the ~`-R` for reverse~ option and `git apply` applies diffs. `git revert` doesn't work on arbitrary diffs, it reverts the specified commits, that's C and D in your example. Can you point to the part of the `git revert` docs that so badly misled you? Something really needs fixing here.

Comment: I admit that I didn't read through the documentation so that was entirely my fault. Thank you for pointing out that I was actually looking for how to apply diffed patches.

Answer (score 0):

Create a patch from the diffed output and apply it:

```
git checkout B
git diff B..D > temp.patch
git apply temp.patch
rm temp.patch
# select hunks
git add -p
```

Comment: You can `git diff B D | git apply` rather than going through the temp file.  Note that diff is looking for two commits to diff and interprets the dot notations in its own way; basically every other git command looks for a commit series and uses the more common interpretation.